# Create a general group to which no characters from the nested group are appended

Tags: .net, regex, parsing

The file name has format "[2013]Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip".
Where:

1. [2013] - Id *(it should get into the "id" group without "[]")*
2. Test1 - File name *(it should get into the "name" group)*
3. [23.12.2020 13-34] - Date *(it should get into the "date" group without "[]")*
4. .zip - Extension *(it should get into the "ext" group)*

And there are a number of rules:

1. The extencion (.zip or otherwise) is always present
2. The "name" group can be empty *(format [2013][23.12.2020 13-34].zip)*
3. The groups "id" and "date" are optional and if they are not found everything must fall into the group "name" *(formats: "Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip", "[2013]Test1 .zip", "Test1 .zip")*
4. The entire group may be missing except the extencion *(format ".zip")*

If the format is "[]Test1 [].zip" then the group "name" = "[]Test1 []" or the format is "Te[]st[] 1 .zip" then the group "name" = "Te[]st[] 1" (The characters "[" and "]" cannot be restrictions for the group "name").

I tried to solve the issue like this: `(?:\[+(?'id'[0-9]*)\]+)?(?'name'[^]]*)?(?:\[+(?'data'[.\-:0-9]*)\]+)?(?'ext'\.[.a-zA-Z]+)+`

With this solution the "name" group is delimited by the "]" character which is appropriate. Is is necessary to strictly monitor the absence of the "id" and "date" groups and add all the remaining text to the "name" group (if there is anything left at all). I don`t know how to achieve this, but the idea is to create nested groups that exclude characters from the base if they fall into them.

Is it possible to solve this at all with the help of regular expressions?

> ```
> For examples:
> [2013]Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip
> [2013]Test1 .zip
> Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip
> Test1 .zip
> []Test1 [].zip
> Te[]st[]1 .zip
> [][].zip
> [].zip
> .zip
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

```
^(?:\[(?'id'[0-9]+)\])?(?'name'[^[.]+|.+)?(?:\[(?'data'[.\-:0-9 ]+)\])?(?'ext'\.[.a-zA-Z]+)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/CTLULd/1

Does not quite correspond to the question but is suitable for solving the problem.